# Getting Destructuring error with Rest operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I assume this must be destructuring using a rest statement?  what exactly is this doing?  The problem is, I get an error in WebStorm:

```
const cars = {...this.state.cars}
```

Error: `Unexpected token`

it's referring to the first `{`

Here's the react component method:

```
addCar(car){
    const cars = {...this.state.cars};
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    cars[`car-${timestamp}`] = car;
    this.setState({ cars })
  }
```

I do have babel setup and working because everything else seems to work fine such as import, etc.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the spread properties syntax and it's creating a shallow copy of `this.state.cars`. That means that this line:

```js
cars[`car-${timestamp}`] = car;
```

doesn't result in an additional key being added to `this.state.cars`. That is, it's being used specifically so that `this.state.cars` is *not mutated*.

For spread properties to be included in your Babel configuration, you'd need to be using the [`babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-object-rest-spread/) and [`babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) plugins - which are included in the [`stage-2`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) preset.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)